# No need to have underline in part of the txt

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="action btn-save">{{'SaveTitle' | translate}}({{row.box.length}})
</div>

.btn-save {
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I have above code.. The result of it is: Save(3) with underline for whole but I need underline just for save and I dont want to have underline for (3). would you please help?

Comment: So use a span element inside and style it. Seems odd you call it a button, but it is a div.

Comment: `<div class="action btn-save"><span>{{'SaveTitle' | translate}}</span>({{row.box.length}})</div>` ----- `.btn-save span {text-decoration: underline;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `span` (or other HTML tag) to apply styles more specifically.

```html
<div class="action btn-save">
  <span class="my-underline">{{'SaveTitle' | translate}}</span>
  <span>({{row.box.length}})</span>
</div>

.my-underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you need by defining a tag such as `span` and then using that attribute in the HTML like so by changing its properties:

css

```
span {
 text-decoration: underline; 
}
```

html

```
<div class="action btn-save"> <span>{{'SaveTitle' | translate}}</span>({{row.box.length}})
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this one but still I have undeline under the digit!!

Answer (score 0):

enclose the text you want to underline inside a span tag and desribe it to be underlined.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).